# How do I expand all row nodes in AG Grid SSRM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am implementing a feature that expands all ag grid row groups of a Partial Store SSRM grid up to the leaf nodes.

You can take a look at [my current implementation in this link](https://plnkr.co/edit/vwJlYEdAxZQMJbls?open=index.jsx&preview).

The problem is knowing when the grid has fully loaded. My current implementation uses `gridApi.getCacheBlockState()` to try to infer whenever all of the partial stores are loaded, but values keep being added to this object as new stores are added, giving false positives if all of them count as `loaded`.

I basically need a way of knowing when I should stop listening to `displayedRowsChanged` events, or in other words, how do I know my grid is fully expanded?

Also, it should be more performant if I had a way of walking the whole partial store tree asynchronously as rows are loaded instead of iterating over all nodes for each render. Is there a way of doing something like that in ag grid?

Custom menu with expand all:
[image]

After clicking on "Expand All", not every row was expanded:
[image]